# How to show tilde in superscript

Tags: tilde, superscripts

I would like to show a tilde in the superscript of a letter. For example

```
F^{\tilde{}}
```

But it does not look good. Any suggestions?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you want something that looks like F<sup>~</sup>, and that you're just using the tilde as a "squiggle" to name something. If you're in math mode, `F^{\sim}` looks more like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The "~" rendering depends on the font, some have centre base, some are positioned much higher (more like "^" and less like "-") Play around with different fonts to get a wanted non-ugly "~".